# Image Map on Dreamweaver

Tags: html

I am doing this class course where I do things from the book and the book asks to use Dreamweaver's ‘hotspot’ for the Image Map. When I tried using it, it seems nothing works and when I put the pages with the image map through the [validator](https://validator.w3.org/), it says the `<img>` element with `<usemap>` attribute mustn’t appear as a descendant of the `<a>` element, but the hash-name reference in attribute `<usemap>` referred to `<Home>`, but there is no map element with a name attribute with that value. I even tried typing in the image map code manually but that doesn’t work. What can I do or what does it need in order for the validator to pass?

```
<header class="fluid header_div">
<a href="index.html" target="_top">
<img src="assets/transparent.gif" alt="Link to homepage" width="910" height="140" usemap="#Home"/>
</a>
</header>
```

Comment: Which Dreamweaver's version you're using?

Comment: I don't think I've seen anyone use an image map in the wild since the 90s. It sounds like you have a very, very out of date book.

Answer (score 0):

First pick one:

- Use a link
- Use an image map

If you want a link (which you say you don't) then:

**Remove the usemap**

```
<a href="index.html" target="_top">
    <img src="assets/transparent.gif" alt="homepage" width="910" height="140">
</a>
```

If you want [an image map](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#image-maps-0):

**Remove the link**

```
<img src="assets/transparent.gif" alt="some navigation thing" width="910" height="140" usemap="#Home">
<map name="Home"><!-- Needs to match the usemap --> 
    <area shape="poly" 
       coords="0,0,0,50,50,50"
       href="index.html" 
       alt="Home">
</map>
```

Adjust coordinates and add other areas to suit.